# What is the proper format when you provide each possible outcome in an if-else chain?

Tags: conventions

I ask this in terms of Java, but it could apply to other languages that follow a similar compiler pattern as well.

This can apply to any type of method where you provide all possible outcomes, but I will use a `boolean` method as an example. I have listed 2 ways to code this method:

**Example 1:**

```
public boolean example1(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
        return true;
    } else if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
        return false;
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        //do something 3
        return false;
    } //could also be in an "else" block.
    return false; //impossible to reach, but necessary to compile.
}
```

Positives:

1. Allows for future viewers of the method to immediately determine exactly what the method does.

Negatives

1. A bit "hacky", and almost unclean.

**Example 2:**

```
public boolean example2(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
        return true;
    } else if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
        return false;
    } else { //The same as (value1 > value2)
        //do something 3
        return false;
    }
}
```

Positives:

1. Is not immediately clear what the method does. (Although this could be prevented with proper documentation)

Negatives

1. Not immediately obvious what the method does.
2. The else, at least to me, might imply that the only important comparisons are the first 2. After all, else means "everything else", which might be misleading and/or confusing.

These methods do the exact same thing. However, I believe that Example 1 is easier to read than Example 2, simply because it explicitly states the last if statement in the if-else chain. At the same time, Example 1 feels extremely, for the lack of a better word, dirty to me.

**Is there a proper way to do this, or is it just personal preference?**

**EDIT:** I chose to not include a set of if statements (not in an if-else chain) because I know for a fact that it is not a good way to do this. If someone disagrees with this and has a valid reason for doing so, please post below, and I will modify my question.

**EDIT 2:** The reason for this opinion is because if "do something" is, for example, 100+ lines of code, not having the if-else chain would reduce readability substantially. In short examples where "do something" is only 1 or several lines of code, then yes, that might be viable. For this reason, I will add it as a third example below (although I still don't think it's very readable, but that's personal preference.)

**Example 3:**

```
public boolean example1(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
        return true;
    }
    if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
        return false;
    }
    //do something 3
    return false;
}
```

Positives:

1. Easier to read (for some people) when "do something" is only several lines of code.
2. Removes the technically redundant "else" statements.

Negatives

1. Much more difficult to read in situations where "do something" is hundreds of lines of code.
2. Having the "do something 3" outside of an if-statement indicates at first glance that the line will always be run, until the return statements are noticed in the previous if-statements.

**Example 4 (and my personal favorite):**

```
public boolean example1(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
    } else if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        //do something 3
    }
    return value1 == value2;
}
```

This is great because it takes care of the "do something" first, and then confines the return statement into a separate, clean, easy to read statement, with no "hacky" repercussions.

Comment: I use option 2 because there's no redundancy. If there are three outcomes and you've tested for two, all that's left is the third.

Comment: Just a note: Currently you have [15 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3144349/user3144349?tab=questions) and no accepted answer. Please remember to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to a question when it solves your problem.

Comment: @Boann Did not know you were supposed to accept an answer, I will go through my previous questions and do that now. Thank you.

Comment: This situation is really too simple to answer one way or the other.  The question you need ask is whether or not the code expresses the comparison you are trying to make.  How would you explain what the code does to a non-dev?

Comment: @Boann Just went through and deleted questions that serve no benefit to the community, and chose my accepted answer for those that in my opinion do. Thank you again for letting me know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'm a fan of only having one `return` statement when it makes sense. For your code, I think it does. So, I would use...

**Option 3:**

```
public boolean example1(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
    } else if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        //do something 3
    }
    return value1 == value2;
}
```

This particular structure doesn't always make sense, but since you're always returning `value1 == value2` anyway, I think it clears things up a bit to only do it once at the end.

To anyone coming along and glancing at the code, it will be pretty clear what is happening. The method always completes in the same location with the same value, and there is a simple bit of workflow logic before that.

Comment: No, he's got some `//do something` stuff in there too.

Comment: Your edit is definitely my personal favorite. Adding that to my post now.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, this is a matter of preference. The third `if` in the first example is redundant, and some IDEs will even warn about it.
Personally, I'd go with the second, as I despise writing code that is redundant, but it all boils down to project standards and personal preferences.

EDIT:
Actually, if we're talking about personal preferences, I'd remove the `else`s altogether - if you enter an `if` block you just `return` out of the function, so the `else if` and `else` are redundant:

```
public boolean example1(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
        return true;
    } 

    if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
        return false;
    } 

    //do something 3
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't know for certain why the downvote, but if you look at my (similar) answer, you'll see I got rebuked for dropping the `else`s! Just a stylistic thing, IMO (as you've noted), as long as it doesn't impinge on readability.

Comment: @Mureinik for the same reason as on chiastic-security's answer. *This will mislead future developers glancing quickly at the code to understand it's behavior.*

Comment: @LukeWillis I strongly disagree with you (regardless of the downvote). Unwrapping useless else blocks is not just OK, it's even encouraged in some projects' standards.

Comment: @LukeWillis Eclipse's auto-generated `equals()` methods use this style.

Comment: I agree that it is a fairly pervasive pattern. Experienced people will recognise what's going on immediately, but I think it can be a little confusing the first time it's encountered. Like you said, it's primarily chocked up to preference.

Comment: @LukeWillis Yes, it's personal preference. That's what makes a downvote seem a bit harsh. A downvote says it's *bad*, not that it's fine but not your cup of tea.

Comment: @chiastic-security fair enough. You may have your internet points back, Mureinik.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 is much better. In example 1, the system has to go through another set of 'Validation' whereas in Example 2, after 2 Validation, it just continues with the default operation.

So at least 1 less operation in Example 2.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 is

```
public boolean example2(final int value1, final int value2) {
    if (value1 == value2) {
        //do something 1
        return true;
    }

    if (value1 < value2) {
        //do something 2
        return false;
    }

    //The same as (value1 > value2)
    //do something 3
    return false;
}
```

In other words, you don't really need the `else` if there's a `return` statement at the end of each block and if it's clear what it's doing.

This is what I prefer when the code blocks are very short. If they're long, then it's hard to notice the `return` statements.

Comment: Strongly disagree. This will mislead future developers glancing quickly at the code to understand it's behavior.

Comment: I was going to add this, but to me this provides the same issue as Example 2. This is definitely personal preference, but when I look at a method like this, an if-else chain immediately tells me that only 1 block of code can be executed.

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere It certainly would if the blocks were more than a couple of lines, but I don't think it's at all misleading if they're short.

Comment: @chiastic-security "do something X" could potentially be hundreds of lines of code, depending on the context.

Comment: @user3144349 That's exactly what I covered in the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @user3144349 not in good code. If it gets to more than three lines, it should be extracted into another method.

Comment: @user3144349 and I am amused to see that Mureinik has edited his post to say that this is also his preference, but he's getting no flak for it!

Comment: Perhaps 100 is overkill. You are definitely right that the code should be split into helper methods in this case. However, even with 10-15 lines (which is viable if the code is unique and only used in one spot), I think that having the statements in a chain enhances the overall readability of the code. But that's personal preference, and I can see how others would disagree with me.